# Java Jersey Newbie Q: Import Statement Error?

Tags: java, import, jersey, webresource

I'm working on making a REST call from Jersey, using [docs from blogs.oracle.com](https://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/consuming_restful_web_services_with). Here's my import statement to get access to WebResource:

```
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
```

I'm getting the error, "Cannot resolve symbol 'Client'". How can I correct this?

**UPDATE with requested info:**

Here's the complete code required to reproduce the anomaly on my installation:

```
package com.nc4.cdn.jcdn.jersey.resource;
import com.sun.jersey.api.*;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource; //<==error on this line -- "Cannot resolve symbol 'Client'"
```

Per request, here is a list of all files in my library folder:

```
apache-maven-2.0.9.jar
asm-3.1.jar
classworlds-1.1.jar
commons-cli-1.0.jar
commons-httpclient-2.0.2.jar
commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
doxia-sink-api-1.0-alpha-10.jar
jdom-1.0.jar
jersey-core-1.0.jar
jersey-server-1.0.jar
jettison-1.3.8.jar
META-INF
jettison
jsch-0.1.27.jar
jsr311-api-1.0.jar
jtidy-4aug2000r7-dev.jar
junit-3.8.1.jar
maven-artifact-2.0.9.jar
maven-artifact-manager-2.0.9.jar
maven-core-2.0.9.jar
maven-error-diagnostics-2.0.9.jar
maven-model-2.0.9.jar
maven-monitor-2.0.9.jar
maven-plugin-api-2.0.jar
maven-plugin-descriptor-2.0.9.jar
maven-plugin-parameter-documenter-2.0.9.jar
maven-plugin-registry-2.0.9.jar
maven-profile-2.0.9.jar
maven-project-2.0.9.jar
maven-reporting-api-2.0.9.jar
maven-repository-metadata-2.0.9.jar
maven-settings-2.0.9.jar
maven-toolchain-2.0.9.jar
maven-wadl-plugin-1.0.jar
maven-wadl-plugin-1.0-sources.jar
plexus-container-default-1.0-alpha-9-stable-1.jar
plexus-interactivity-api-1.0-alpha-4.jar
plexus-utils-1.5.1.jar
slide-webdavlib-2.1.jar
stax-api-1.0.1.jar
xml
META-INF
wagon-file-1.0-beta-2.jar
wagon-http-lightweight-1.0-beta-2.jar
wagon-http-shared-1.0-beta-2.jar
wagon-provider-api-1.0-beta-2.jar
wagon-ssh-1.0-beta-2.jar
wagon-ssh-common-1.0-beta-2.jar
wagon-ssh-external-1.0-beta-2.jar
wagon-webdav-1.0-beta-2.jar
xercesImpl-2.6.1.jar
xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar
xml-im-exporter-1.1.jar
```

Comment: suppose you import the correct `jersey-client` for the project. refer this [post](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/restful-java-client-with-jersey-client/)

Comment: Please specify the correct import statement, @RajithPemabandu. As noted in my subject line, I'm a Java newbie!

Comment: @RajithPemabandu, are you referring to `import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;` as in that post? I get the same error using those statements.

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the Client class also:

```
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
```

(Most IDEs can automatically organise your imports for you)

You also need jersey-client-1.0.jar in your classpath

Comment: With the following import lines, I still get the "Cannot resolve symbol 'Client'" error: `import org.glassfish.jersey.client.*;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
`

Comment: @VikR there's not enough information in your question to help anymore. You need to post the smallest amount of code that reproduces you issue, and give more information on what libraries you have on your classpath.

Comment: I've added more info to the original post. Please let me know if I can add more info.

Comment: @ Catchwa what's the correct `import` statement to use in order to access `jersey-client-1.0`?

Comment: @VikR you already have it. You just need the JAR file in your libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the import statement to:

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.client.*;
```

...fixed it.